# Как получить данные UDP?

Tags: сокеты, udp, c++, winsock, сниффер

Пишу простенький сниффер на с++ по примеру. Вот рабочий код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE    0x10000
#define SIO_RCVALL         0x98000001
// Буфер для приёма данных
char Buffer[MAX_PACKET_SIZE]; // 64 Kb

//Структура заголовка IP-пакета

typedef struct IPHeader {
  UCHAR   iph_verlen;   // версия и длина заголовка
  UCHAR   iph_tos;      // тип сервиса
  USHORT  iph_length;   // длина всего пакета
  USHORT  iph_id;       // Идентификация
  USHORT  iph_offset;   // флаги и смещения
  UCHAR   iph_ttl;      // время жизни пакета
  UCHAR   iph_protocol; // протокол
  USHORT  iph_xsum;     // контрольная сумма
  ULONG   iph_src;      // IP-адрес отправителя
  ULONG   iph_dest;     // IP-адрес назначения
} IPHeader;

char src[10];
char dest[10];
char ds[15];
unsigned short lowbyte;
unsigned short hibyte;

int main(void)
{

  WSADATA     wsadata;   // Инициализация WinSock.
  SOCKET      s;         // Cлущающий сокет.
  char        name[128]; // Имя хоста (компьютера).
  HOSTENT*    phe;       // Информация о хосте.
  SOCKADDR_IN sa;        // Адрес хоста
  IN_ADDR sa1;        //
  unsigned long        flag = 1;  // Флаг PROMISC Вкл/выкл.

  // инициализация
  WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata);
  s = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP );
  gethostname(name, sizeof(name));
  phe = gethostbyname( name );
  ZeroMemory( &sa, sizeof(sa) );
  sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sa.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr *)phe->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;
  bind(s, (SOCKADDR *)&sa, sizeof(SOCKADDR));

  // Включение promiscuous mode.
  ioctlsocket(s, SIO_RCVALL, &flag);

  // Бесконечный цикл приёма IP-пакетов.
  while( !_kbhit() )
  {
    unsigned int count;
    count = recv( s, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 0 );
    // обработка IP-пакета
    if( count >= sizeof(IPHeader) )
    {
      IPHeader* hdr = (IPHeader *)Buffer;
      //Начинаем разбор пакета...

    strcpy_s(src,"Пакет: ");
    //CharToOem(src,dest);
    //system (dest);
    printf(dest);
    // Преобразуем в понятный вид адрес отправителя.
    printf("From ");
    sa1.s_addr = hdr->iph_src;
    printf(inet_ntoa(sa1));

    // Преобразуем в понятный вид адрес получателя.
    printf(" To ");
    sa1.s_addr = hdr->iph_dest;
    printf(inet_ntoa(sa1));

    // Вычисляем протокол. Полный список этих констант
    // содержится в файле winsock2.h
    printf(" Prot: ");
    if(hdr->iph_protocol == IPPROTO_TCP) printf("TCP ");
    if(hdr->iph_protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) printf("UDP ");

    // Вычисляем размер. Так как в сети принят прямой порядок
    // байтов, а не обратный, то прийдётся поменять байты местами.
    printf("Size: ");
    lowbyte = hdr->iph_length>>8;
    hibyte = hdr->iph_length<<8;
    hibyte = hibyte + lowbyte;
    //printf("%s",itoa(hibyte,ds,10));
    printf("%u", hibyte);

    // Вычисляем время жизни пакета.
    printf(" TTL:%s",itoa(hdr->iph_ttl,ds,10));
    printf("\n");

    }
  }

  closesocket( s );
  WSACleanup();
}
```

Еще нужно будет прописать #pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

В теории пакет будет состоять из ip хидер + udp хидер + data.
Размер ip постояннный: 20 байт. Размер udp хидера вроде такой

```
struct udpheader {
unsigned short int uh_sport;
unsigned short int uh_dport;
unsigned short int uh_len;
unsigned short int uh_check;
}; /* total udp header length: 8 bytes (=64 bits) */
```

После этого идут данные udp

В ip содержится длина пакета вместе с ip хидером.
Нужно взять размер пакета в ip вычесть из него размер ip header и размер
udp хидера, и тогда получим смещение на данные udp.
А также вычитанием ip.length - смещение на данные = получим размер данных.

Надеюсь, я правильно думаю. Но как это реализовать попроще? Помогите с кодом, пожалуйста. Ну хотя бы как эти 2 структуры (IPHeader и udpheader) объединить чтобы потом работать с ними. Есть еще один [пример](http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-in-c-using-winsock/) на Си, но он как то странно работает, за 10 минут записал в лог всего 2 пакета.

Comment: @Merlin, а Ваша программа работает?

From, To ... сыпятся на экран?

Comment: да все нормально работает, вот [скомпиленный ехе][1]  


  [1]: http://rghost.ru/40213433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По простому

```
u_char *data; // будет указывать на данные пользователя
size_t  data_len;
size_t  headers_len;
struct udpheader *udp_hdr;
....
count = recv( s, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 0 );
// обработка IP-пакета
if( count >= sizeof(IPHeader) )
{
  IPHeader* hdr = (IPHeader *)Buffer;
  ...
  if(hdr->iph_protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
     udp_hdr = (struct udpheader *)(Buffer+sizeof(*hdr));
     data = (u_char *)(Buffer+(headers_len = sizeof(*hdr)+sizeof(*udp_hdr)));
     data_len = count - headers_len;
.....
```